# Creating Merged Folder of Symlinks on macOS

Tags: macos, symlink

I'm attempting to use the perl script below to create symlinks of all folders from three locations. My desired result would be something like:

> **Source**
> /TV720/GoT/Season00/
>
> /TV1080/GoT/Season01/
>
> /TV2160/GoT/Season02/
>
> **Destination (Symlink)**
>
> /TV/GoT/Season00/
>
> /TV/GoT/Season01/
>
> /TV/GoT/Season02/

However when I run the script, I get: /TV/GoT/Season00/ without the other folders found in other sources.

It appears the 2nd and 3rd source location sub-folders aren't symlinked and merged in the event of duplicate folder names.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @sourceList = (
    "/Volumes/Disk/TV720",
    "/Volumes/Disk/TV1080",
    "/Volumes/Disk/TV2160",
);
my $destinationFolder = "/Volumes/Disk/TV";

foreach my $currentSource (@sourceList) {

    opendir SDIR, $currentSource  or do {
    warn "$0: can't opendir $currentSource: $!\n";
    next;
    };
    my @sourceFolders = grep { not /^\.{1,2}$/ } readdir SDIR;
    closedir SDIR;

    foreach my $currentFolder (sort @sourceFolders) {

    my $fromPath = $currentSource     . '/' . $currentFolder;
    my $toPath   = $destinationFolder . '/' . $currentFolder;

    if (not -e $toPath) {
        # print "Creating $toPath as symlink to $fromPath\n";
        symlink $fromPath, $toPath
        or warn "$0: can't symlink $toPath to $fromPath: $!\n";
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible you have subfolders of the same name in each of your sources?  Do you have any error output?

Edit: It looks like your are iterating GoT in each source and trying to create a symlink to destinationFolder/GoT.  What you probably want is to create a subdirectory in each of the destinations and then go one deeper to symlink the contents found in the sourceFolder for each source.

Comment: @IanPilipski Correct. I prefer to keep my media in three top level folders based on quality (<720, 1080, and 2160) and my desire is to have a symlinked merge of all folders and contents. Is it possible to merge duplicate folder names when creating symlinks?

Comment: No that is not possible. If you have GoT as a subfolder in each of the source folders, and under each GoT you have unique file names that do not overlap the other resolutions folders, then you can iterate each file and symlink the file itself into a destination directory that you create.

Comment: Yes all of the files and filenames are unique across the source folders. However the Folder names such as GoT and nested folders such as Season 01, Season 02, etc. may be present across sources. How do you suggest handling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the information above, you might be able to accomplish what you want with union mounts on the file system.  This is where you can overlay directories on top of other directories.  It's more advanced than a symlink for sure, but it might do what you want.

If you want to continue with the symlinks, I would suggest modifying your script to loop through your sources and recursively iterate the subfolders in each directory.

Then for each subfolder, create an actual new folder in the destination, then iterate the files in the source subfolder and symlink each file individually.

Comment: I was able to use this bash script to create merged folders, subfolders, and symlinked files. Thanks

`source_folders=("/src1" "/src2")
destination_folder="/dest"

for source_folder in "${source_folders[@]}"; do
    find "$source_folder" -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' dir; do
        new_dir="${dir/$source_folder/$destination_folder}"
        mkdir -p "$new_dir"
    done

    find "$source_folder" -type f ! -name ".DS_Store" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do
        new_file="${file/$source_folder/$destination_folder}"
        ln -s "$file" "$new_file"
    done
done`